# FSC recompiles every time

Tags: scala, compilation, scalac

FSC recompiles my .scala files every time even there is no need - I can compile it twice without editing anything between attempts and it recompiles them! 
For example, I have 2 files

Hello.scala

```
class Hello{
  print("hello")
}
```

And Tokens.scala:

```
abstract class Token(val str: String, val start: Int, val end: Int)
  {override def toString = getClass.getSimpleName + "(" + "[" + start + "-" + end + "]" + str + ")"}
class InputToken(str: String, start: Int, end: Int)
        extends Token(str, start, end)
 class ParsedToken(str: String, start: Int, end: Int, val invisible: Boolean)
        extends Token(str, start, end)
```

When I ask ant to compile project from scratch I see following output:

```
ant compile
init:
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\projects\Test\build\classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\projects\Test\build\test\classes

compile:
      [fsc] Base directory is `D:\projects\Test`
      [fsc] Compiling source files: somepackage\Hello.scala, somepackage\Tokens.scala to D:\projects\Test\build\classes

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Than I don't edit anything and ask ant compile again:

```
ant compile
init:
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\projects\Test\build\classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\projects\Test\build\test\classes

compile:
      [fsc] Base directory is `D:\projects\Test`
      [fsc] Compiling source files: somepackage\Tokens.scala to D:\projects\Test\build\classes

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

As you can see, fsc acts smart in case of Hello.scala (no recompilation) and acts dumb in case of Tokens.scala. I suggest that the problem is somehow related with inheritance but that is all.

So what is wrong?

Comment: FSC will compile everything unless you pass it flags telling it to do transitive dependency analysis. How have you configured the Scala compilation task in Ant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't like much posting stuff written by others, but I think this question merits a more complete answer that what was strictly asked.

So, first of all, `fsc` recompiles everything by default, period. It is `ant`, not `fsc`, which is leaving `Hello.scala` out, because the file name matches the class name. It is not leaving `Tokens.scala` out because there is no class called `Tokens` compiled -- so, in the absence of a `Tokens.class`, it recompiled `Tokens.scala`.

That is the wrong thing to do with Scala. Scala differs in one fundamental aspect from Java in that, because of technical limitations on JVM, a change in a `trait` requires recompilation of every class, object or instantiation that uses it.

Now, one can fix the `ant` task to do a smarter thing starting with Scala 2.8. I'm taking this information from [blogtrader.net](http://blogtrader.net/blog/how_to_setup_dependencies_aware) by Caoyuan, of Scala plugin for Netbeans fame. You define the Scala task on the build target like below:

```
<scalac srcdir="${src.dir}"
        destdir="${build.classes.dir}"
        classpathref="build.classpath"
        force="yes"
        addparams="-make:transitive -dependencyfile ${build.dir}/.scala_dependencies"
        >
    <src path="${basedir}/src1"/> 
    <!--include name="compile/**/*.scala"/-->
    <!--exclude name="forget/**/*.scala"/-->
</scalac>
```

It tells `ant` to recompile everything, as `ant` simply isn't smart enough to figure out what needs to be recompiled or not. It also tells *Scala* to build a file containing compilation dependencies, and use a transitive dependency algorithm to figure out what needs to be recompiled or not.

You also need to change the init target to include the build directory in the build classpath, as Scala will need that to recompile other classes. It should look like this:

```
<path id="build.classpath">
    <pathelement location="${scala-library.jar}"/>
    <pathelement location="${scala-compiler.jar}"/>
    <pathelement location="${build.classes.dir}"/>
</path>
```

For more details, please refer to Caoyuan's blog.

Answer (score 5):

Tokens.scala is recompiled because there isn't a class file matching its basename. That is, it doesn't produce a Tokens.class file. When deciding if a source file should be compiled, fsc looks for a classfile with the same basename and if the class file does not exist or the modification time on the source file is later than that of the class file, the source file will be rebuilt. If you can, I suggest that you look into [Simple Build Tool](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/), its continuous compile mode accurately tracks source->classfile mapping and won't recompile Tokens.scala

For extra laughs, think about what the compiler might do if you have a different source file that has `class Tokens` in it.

Although scala allows arbitrary public classes/objects in any source file, there's still quite a bit of tooling that assumes you will somewhat follow the java convention and at least have one class/object in the file with the same name as the source file basename.

Comment: ahaha, that was "bingo" in 1 second but I missed so much time to write my answer accurately so you were first) Also java convention is not appropriate when you have sealed classes.