# scalac's dependencyfile option doesn't work?

Tags: scala, ant, scalac

I was reading a previous stack overflow question about setting up ant tasks for scalac:
[FSC recompiles every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803672/fsc-recompiles-every-time)

The weird thing is when I test the -dependencyfile option, I find no dependency file generated anywhere. I am testing this with ubuntu's scalac 2.9.1 and also with the official 2.10.2 jar in ant tasks. It seems the command-line utility and the ant task both take my input without complaining anything (they are grammatically correct?) though.

Am I using this feature in the wrong way?

E.g. from command-line:

```
scalac -dependencyfile scala_dependencies *.scala
```

from an ant tasks

```
<!-- inside a macro definition -->
<scalac destdir="@{destdir}" deprecation="yes"
        force="yes" dependencyfile="scala_dependencies"
        addparams="@{addparams}"
        scalacdebugging="true">
   <!-- src, classpath, patternset and etc -->
</scalac>
```

updates:

I added -make:transitive options to comand-line it does generate a file for me but I ran it for the second time, scalac simply crashed.
$ scalac -make:transitive -dependencyfile scala_dependencies *.scala
Recompiling 2 files
warning: there were 1 deprecation warnings; re-run with -deprecation for details
error: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at scala.tools.nsc.io.Path$.apply(Path.scala:73)
        at scala.tools.nsc.dependencies.DependencyAnalysis$$anonfun$saveDependencyAnalysis$1.apply(DependencyAnalysis.scala:33)
        at scala.tools.nsc.dependencies.DependencyAnalysis$$anonfun$saveDependencyAnalysis$1.apply(DependencyAnalysis.scala:33)
        at scala.tools.nsc.dependencies.Files$FileDependencies$$anonfun$emit$1$2$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Files.scala:96)
        at scala.tools.nsc.dependencies.Files$FileDependencies$$anonfun$emit$1$2$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Files.scala:96)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:72)
        at scala.tools.nsc.dependencies.Files$FileDependencies$$anonfun$emit$1$2.apply(Files.scala:96)
        at scala.tools.nsc.dependencies.Files$FileDependencies$$anonfun$emit$1$2.apply(Files.scala:96)
        at scala.collection.mutable.OpenHashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(OpenHashMap.scala:221)
        at scala.collection.mutable.OpenHashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(OpenHashMap.scala:219)
        at scala.collection.mutable.OpenHashMap$$anonfun$foreachUndeletedEntry$1.apply(OpenHashMap.scala:226)
        at scala.collection.mutable.OpenHashMap$$anonfun$foreachUndeletedEntry$1.apply(OpenHashMap.scala:226)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:34)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:38)
        at scala.collection.mutable.OpenHashMap.foreachUndeletedEntry(OpenHashMap.scala:226)
        at scala.collection.mutable.OpenHashMap.foreach(OpenHashMap.scala:219)
        at scala.tools.nsc.dependencies.Files$FileDependencies.emit$1(Files.scala:96)
        at scala.tools.nsc.dependencies.Files$FileDependencies.writeTo(Files.sca
la:103)
        at scala.tools.nsc.dependencies.Files$FileDependencies$$anonfun$writeTo$1.apply(Files.scala:92)
        at scala.tools.nsc.dependencies.Files$FileDependencies$$anonfun$writeTo$1.apply(Files.scala:92)
        at scala.tools.nsc.dependencies.Files$class.writeToFile(Files.scala:163)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$dependencyAnalysis$.writeToFile(Global.scala:498)
        at scala.tools.nsc.dependencies.Files$FileDependencies.writeTo(Files.scala:92)
        at scala.tools.nsc.dependencies.DependencyAnalysis$class.saveDependencies(DependencyAnalysis.scala:87)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$dependencyAnalysis$.saveDependencies(Global.scala:498)
        at scala.tools.nsc.dependencies.DependencyAnalysis$class.saveDependencyAnalysis(DependencyAnalysis.scala:32)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$dependencyAnalysis$.saveDependencyAnalysis(Global.scala:498)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:1022)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1038)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Main$.process(Main.scala:106)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Main$.main(Main.scala:123)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Main.main(Main.scala)

for 2.10.2, the compiler complains:
warning: -make is deprecated: this option is unmaintained.  Use sbt or an IDE for selective recompilation.
and I still can't find the generate file